# How to get dept of selected div with javascript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'd like to get the dept level of a selected div starting from `.element`:

```
<div class="elements">
    <div class="element">
        <div>
            <div>text</div> <!-- example: if click get DEPT level -->
        </div>
        <div>text</div>
    </div>

    <div class="element">
        <div>text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For this problem I'm using a algorithm that works like a tree (top to bottom), the problem is that it only get the dept of `firstChild` instead of getting the dept of the selected (`this`) element.

```
document.querySelector(".elements div").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var text = this,
        level = 0,
        parent = this.closest('.element'); //starting point is '.element'

    while (parent != null) {
        parent = parent.firstChild; //Problem: get 'this' instead of firstChild
        level += 1;
        console.log('dept: ', level);
        console.log('parent: ', parent);

        //fallback for not crashing the browser
        if (level > 15) {return false;}
    }
});
```

What is the cleanest way of doing so **without JQuery**?

Comment: You can use recursion. Something like: `hasChild() + 1` and `hasChild` would return `0` if no children otherwise 1.

Comment: Your code already uses `$(document).on`. Why are you opposed to jquery?

Comment: @HijikataAmamyia You have a small error in your JS, "#Problem: get firstChild instead of 'this'" should be "// Problem: get firstChild instead of 'this' ".

Comment: @gurvinder372 Removed it

Comment: @HijikataAmamyia Rather than traversing from top to bottom, I have suggested a solution that traverse bottom (clicked element) to top (.element).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, you will have to use recursion for this.

#### Logic:

- Create utility functions `hasChildren` that will check if element is not undefined and the length of `.children` is than `0`.
- Create a function that will recursively loop and calculate depth.

  - Create an array to loop. This will be either Array from `element.children` or Array of passed HTML collection.
  - For a given level, `return 1 + nextIteration`.
  - If no child, `return 1` as you are looping on children.
  - Use `.map` to calculate depth of all trees and get the max value.

```js
function registerEvents() {
  var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);
  }
}

function hasChildren(element) {
  return !!(element.children && element.children.length);
}

function calculateDepth(elements) {
  var list = elements.constructor.name === 'HTMLCollection' ? [].concat(elements) : Array.from(elements.children);
  var depths = list.map(function(element) {
    if (hasChildren(element)) {
      return 1 + calculateDepth(element)
    } else {
      return 1;
    }
  });
  depths.push(0);
  return Math.max.apply(null, depths);
}

function handleClick(event) {
  var depth = calculateDepth(this);
  console.log(depth);
  event.stopPropagation()
}

registerEvents();
```

```css
div.tile,
.tile div {
  margin: 10px;
  min-height: 30px;
  width: auto;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div class='tile'>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div> A</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div>B</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='tile'></div>
```

Comment: You are calculating the dept of all div instead of the selected ones, for instance if I click the ont 3rd div it will always return 6 instead of the clicked one (which would be dept:3), https://jsfiddle.net/0a5pk715/

Comment: @HijikataAmamyia If you see, I had registered click on parent div only. Have updated code to register on all divs.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the child element using the `firstChild` and `nextSibling` property and compare and store the maximum child level in globally.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the `parentNode` has class element, if not keep traversing upwards.

```
var elementList = document.querySelectorAll( ".element div" );
Array.from( elementList ).forEach( s => s.addEventListener( "click" , function(e){
    var el = e.currentTarget;
    var counter = 1;
    while( el.parentNode.classList.contains( "element" ) )
    { 
       el = el.parentNode;
       counter++;
    }
    console.log("level", counter);
    e.stopPropagation();
}));
```

**Demo**

```js
var elementList = document.querySelectorAll( ".element div" );
Array.from( elementList ).forEach( s => s.addEventListener( "click" , function(e){
    var el = e.currentTarget;
    var counter = 1;
    while( el.parentNode.classList.contains( "element" ) )
    { 
       el = el.parentNode;
       counter++;
    }
    console.log("level", counter);
    e.stopPropagation();
}));
```

```html
<div class="elements">
  <div class="element">
    <div>
      <div>text</div>
      <!-- example: if click get DEPT level -->
    </div>
    <div>text</div>
  </div>

  <div class="element">
    <div>text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd have prefered a solution top to bottom, but I tried the script and it has some problems see https://jsfiddle.net/k59gtoxt/9/ for more details.

Comment: You need to wrap a text in an element so that a click event on that can be identified individually. Currently it is identifying the click event on the first element child of the element on which you are clicking.